# Does a higher variable value use more computing power?

Tags: java, variables, double, max

I want to return a max value from a method and I have two ways of achieving this:

1. I could use a number that won't be reached ever by the calculation, like 10000
2. I could `return Double.MAX_VALUE`

My question now is: Is there a difference in terms of speed, RAM usage etc?

Comment: No, why would there be? A double is always stored as a 64-bit format IEEE 754 value, i.e. 8 bytes.

Comment: All operations on a variable involve all of its bits. So there is no computational difference between 1 and 1000000 if they are stored in the same type

Comment: As others said there isn't, but you could use float instead of double because it takes only 4 bytes instead of 8, since you said that it won't reach over 10000 anyway.

Comment: oh right, I always use doubles instinctively even though I don't need them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no difference. A `double` will always use the same number of bits in its representation.

A Java `double` is an implementation of the IEEE-754 standard.

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

---

If you want to represent "no maximum," however, a better way might be to use an [`OptionalDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html).